# Adding Categories To Drupal

Tags: drupal

I am a newbie to drupal
I have to develop a website in drupal
In which i want to add three categories of content
I want these categories in top in main menu 
Recipes , News and Studies these are the three categories.

Now when user wants to post a article an category is asked from him and when he add article then the categories will be shown to there respective page.

Can anybody tell me how to do this in drupal

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Taxonomy module** for the defining categories.
You can refer to [this](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/taxonomy)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could also make 3 different content types which allows different fields etc. Read more [here](http://drupal.org/node/21947). If you just want tagging Taxonomy will be great though.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Taxonomy Module, which is a part of Drupal core. Drupal's name for what's commonly known as "tags" or "categories" is "terms," and "terms" are organized into "taxonomies."

So, you'd want to create a "taxonomy" called "Categories" and load your 3 "terms" into it, which would end up organized like this:

- Categories (Taxonomy)

  - Recipes (Term)
  - News (Term)
  - Studies (Term)

You can even go multiple tears to add an extra layer of organization to your terms, for instance:

- Categories

  - Recipes

    - Breakfast
    - Lunch
    - Dinner
    - Dessert
  - News
  - Studies